# Function that sets x axis tick marks correctly from a maximum x axis value, and a given tick width

Tags: for-loop, go

This should be a relatively simple thing to do, but I can't seem to get it right here. I am generating PDF and so it's not as simple as using coordinates

What I am doing is making an x axis that's larger than the max x value for cosmetic reasons. In my example, **the max x is 19, but I want the max value on the axis to be 20**

The tricky bit is that the *gaps between the points on the chart are set based on the number of points and available space* for the chart

Laying out my example, I know these pieces of information:

- max x = 19
- max x axis value = 20
- The width of the x axis = 518.3
- The number of tick marks I want = 10

I thought it would be as simple as this to get the space between each tick to set in a loop that draws the little tick marks:

```
    interateXPositionsForEachTick := (xAxisWidth / xAxisMaxValue) * (xAxisMaxValue / NumberOfTickMarksOnXAxis)
```

In the above we are doing:

```
(518.3 / 20) * (20 / 10)
```

This logic is right isn't it?

But it doesn't seem to work in my loop at all:

```
xAxisTickPosition := startOfYAxis
for i := 1.0; i <= NumberOfTickMarksOnXAxis; i++ {

    LabelToUse := (xAxisMaxValue / NumberOfTickMarksOnXAxis) * i

    Line(xAxisTickPosition, placeYTickLocation, xAxisTickPosition, placeYTickLocation+tickmarkSize)

    xAxisTickPosition = xAxisTickPosition + interateXPositionsForEachTick
```

But this doesn't work:

[image]

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here? I am baffled

**The 20 at the end is being set outside of this, but I want this function to be able to basically put a 20 in the same place** I set it outside so I can test my function's alignment

**I found out that it is 1.5 widths too large compared to the x axis:**

When running this to make it 15% smaller:

```
interateXPositionsForEachTick := ((xAxisWidth / xAxisMaxValue) * (xAxisMaxValue NumberOfTickMarksOnXAxis)) * 0.85
```

The chart's axis looks correct: 
[image]

The 20 is bolded because it's overwritten outside of my loop

Comment: You can see that the widths between the axis aren't set right

Comment: I would guess your number of 518.3 should start from the far left of the page, where the y axis labels are.  The x labels are too wide and I guess this is the reason

Comment: That should be correct since it's the width that's used to set the length of the x axis, which is drawn nicely

Comment: Looks like error from float numbers rounding is getting accumulated if you calculate it in cycle. Try not to add values in cycle, but calculate fresh values every time. Like `xAxisTickPosition = tickWidth * (i-1)` and `endPosition = tickWidth * i`